# How to load external page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a link button that supposed to link to another page. The content of that page should be displayed to the current page. I'm using the bootstrap framework, however the function I created doesn't seem to work.

here's my code;

```
<a href="" id="reslink">link1</a>

<div class="span8" id="maincont"></div>
```

javascript;

```
$('#reslink').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sample.html",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            $('#maincont').html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Bootstrap (a style and DOM framework)?

Comment: Seems like a straightforward ajax call. There's not much here with which to troubleshoot, though.

Comment: are you calling your `$.ajax` inside `$(document).ready(function(){....})`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have following ways.

**First**

use html as below,.

```
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" id="reslink">link1</a>
```

`Javascript:void(0);` work as return false from script.

**Second**

Do not change anything in html code but make below change in `jQuery` code.

```
$('#reslink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sample.html",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            $('#maincont').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` **prevent the default behavior** of the `HTML` so you can execute your code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) would be a better choice for you?

```
$("#reslink").click(function() {
    $("#maincont").load("sample.html");
});
```

Be mindful that loading content in this way could potentially break History and Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

`body onload="abc()"` in the loaded page should work when rendered from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods worked for me. It worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //ajax load page
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                type: 'ajax'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //find body and replace
                $('#content').html(data);
                setStyle();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that you should not send the entire html in this. You only need to indicate where the body should be changed.

Place this code in the **head** section

[Example](https://raw.githack.com/akbarali1/jquery-load-page/main/index.html)