# How to display returned html page in a div using javascript and/or html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a url, send the url and display the returned html page in a div or any block element on the same page.
Ultimately, what I want to do is send a request as soon as the user enters a name, create a div to display the response,
fill the div with the response, hide the div then display a button or tab for the user to click to see the returned document.
But for now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the response into a div on the same page.

This seems like a fundamental HTML activity but I can't figure out how to direct the returned page to a div instead of having it replace the original page.
I would prefer to do this with plain HTML5 and javascript, not JQuery, but if JQuery is the only way I'll tackle that learning curve.

```
<html>
<body onload="buildPage()">
    <div id="documents"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function buildPage() {
        var name="somename" ;  // this will eventually come from user input and be passed in
        var documentName = name + ".html";
        var url ="http://localhost:8080/docserver/getpage?name=" + documentName;

        // create a div to display the requested document
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = documentName;
        newDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

        // ... probably need to do something here to direct the url response into the new div

        // nest the newDiv in the existing div
        document.getElementById("documents").appendChild(newDiv) ;

        //TBD create a button to display the returned document
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You most probably want to look at using jQuery to make an AJAX call, then grabbing the HTML from the .success callback and again using jQuery to dump that into a div. Sounds harder than it actually is. Some gentle Googling around should yield decent results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load external page using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375929/how-to-load-external-page-using-ajax)

Comment: Thanks jonny,  I've just spent five hours googling and got nowhere, that is why I'm here.

Comment: Key term for your googling: **ajax**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to make an ajax request, which returns html, then render that html in a div?

I would also recommend using jQuery if you are not. It will make your life a lot easier.

Your file(s) will need to look something like this:

**HTML**

```
....
<div id="mydiv"></div>
....
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'get',
        'contentType': 'text/plain',
        'url': 'path/to/your/script/',
        'dataType': 'html',
        'timeout': 50000
    }).done(function (data) {
        // success
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

For the sake of simplicity, Let's say your html that is returned is:

**HTML**

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Your page (after the ajax request runs) will look like this:

**HTML**

```
....
<div id="mydiv"><p>Hello World!</p></div>
....
```

This should get you rolling.

Comment: This is a far better answer (almost textbook) than mine. This makes me sad :(

Comment: dragonslovetacos, thanks for the nice reply.  Here is my quandry: I don't want to use JQuery.  Since HTML is all about sending requests and displaying the resulting page I assumed there was a dead simply way of doing what I want.  Are you saying that AJAX is the only solution?

Comment: No, jQuery provides helper wrappers around JavaScript functionality. You can do it yourself in pure JavaScript using "xmlhttprequest" http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest is correct, you don't need to use jQuery, you don't need to drive a car to get where you are going either. It's just a lot easier than walking sometimes. For example, look at my script above - it's just an ajax call. Compare that to all of the javascript you had to write below. It just makes things "easier". :)

Comment: Just as a closing note, I would suggest you accept this answer by dragonslovetacos as, in my opinion, it is a really clear and concise example of what you were initially asking.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, this code will pretty much do it for you

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mypage.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```

With really good supporting documentation found here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am really confused.  A few days ago I fooled around with the JQuery Tabs widget.  If you pass a URL when creating a tab, the content is automatically loaded when the tab is clicked.  Is JQuery using AJAX under the hood to do this?  I really did not understand the Tabs examples but it appeared that an iframe was involved.  I gave up on JQuery because I got a 1.9 solution mostly working then found that tabs.add() and tabs.remove() are deprecated.  So I went back to a 'pure' html/js solution.

Comment: So you want tabs content to be loaded / refreshed from a server when that tab is clicked, and be able to create / remove tabs dynamically? Under the hood jQuery wraps the xmlhttprequest object to make it more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that answered my query.  Especially jonny who did some impressive hand holding.  I really don't understand JQuery so I wanted a pure html/js solution.  Here is what I ended up doing.

```
function buildPage() {
    var name="somename" ;  // this will eventually come from user input and be passed in
    var documentName = name + ".html";
    var url="http://localhost:8080/FDS/documents?filename=" + documentName ;

    // create a div to display the requested document
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = documentName;
    //newDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

    // create an iframe to place in the div
    var newIframe = document.createElement("iframe") ;
    newIframe.src = url ;

    // nest the iframe in the div just created
    newDiv.appendChild(newIframe) ;

    // nest the newDiv in the existing div
    document.getElementById("documents").appendChild(newDiv) ;
```

The missing component was an iframe.  I thought I saw JQuery using iframes in the tabs widget but I did not pursue that avenue until it looked like I was going to get only JQuery based replies.